# Developing QGIS plugin on Mac - GDAL

Tags: gdal, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, qgis-2, mac

I'm developing a plugin for QGIS called [DEMtools.](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DEMTools/) It runs fine on my linux machine, but is causing me headaches when run on Mac OS X Mavericks  (surprise, surprise). I keep getting segmentation faults that look like they are caused by GDAL accessing a GTiffDataset.

Does anyone have any experience debugging these kinds of problems with qgis plugins in the Mac OS X environment? For starters I'd like to know where in my code this goes pear shaped, but as it crashes QGIS entirely, printing messages to the QGIS python console isn't an option.

**UPDATE:**

> I get the same error running in Safe Mode.

**UPDATE 2:**

> I've got Eclipse+PyDev up and running for better debugging. [This](http://linfiniti.com/2011/12/remote-debugging-qgis-python-plugins-with-pydev/)
>   post is helpful with that. I've identified the problem, but I haven't
>   found a fix yet.
>
> As should have been clear initially from the first 6 lines of the backtrace, the problem is the GDALClose. My code didn't explicitly close the dataset and was relying on the gdal `__del__` method after it moved out of scope.
>
> However, even when I explicitly close the data set, 
>   `dataSet = None`
>   the same problem occurs **within QGIS.**
>
> When I open the python editor from the terminal I can use the gdal module to open and close the same file all day without a problem. (and as stated earlier, it works in linux)
>   I am very close to being totally stumped. Any thoughts?

Also, I'd be really interested to know if any one can successfully run the plugin and/or duplicate this error in the Mac environment.

Below is (part of) the crash log:

```
Process:         QGIS [511]
Path:            /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
Identifier:      org.qgis.qgis2
Version:         2.0.1 (2.0.1 [f738351])
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [262]
Responsible:     QGIS [511]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-05-26 12:58:19.517 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
Report Version:  11


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010a8fd000-000000010af86000 [ 6692K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   org.gdal.gdal                   0x000000010d45d2bb GDALMultiDomainMetadata::Clear() + 55
1   org.gdal.gdal                   0x000000010d2c0e40 GTiffRasterBand::~GTiffRasterBand() + 32
2   org.gdal.gdal                   0x000000011cce6fb9 GDALDataset::~GDALDataset() + 485
3   org.gdal.gdal                   0x000000011cb8855d GTiffDataset::~GTiffDataset() + 117
4   org.gdal.gdal                   0x000000011cce53bb GDALClose + 146
5   _gdal.so                        0x000000011ca896e7 _wrap_delete_Dataset + 279
6   org.python.python               0x000000011a8c3f72 PyObject_Call + 101
7   org.python.python               0x000000011a8c07d1 PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs + 190
8   _gdal.so                        0x000000011ca69d43 SwigPyObject_dealloc + 94
9   org.python.python               0x000000011a8ee88f 0x11a8ba000 + 215183
10  org.python.python               0x000000011a90db4c 0x11a8ba000 + 342860
11  org.python.python               0x000000011a8dfe7c 0x11a8ba000 + 155260
12  org.python.python               0x000000011a94087c 0x11a8ba000 + 551036
13  org.python.python               0x000000011a93d4d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
14  org.python.python               0x000000011a93a093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
15  org.python.python               0x000000011a8e1796 0x11a8ba000 + 161686
16  org.python.python               0x000000011a8c3f72 PyObject_Call + 101
17  org.python.python               0x000000011a8ce9a7 0x11a8ba000 + 84391
18  org.python.python               0x000000011a8c3f72 PyObject_Call + 101
19  org.python.python               0x000000011a94001f PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
20  sip.so                          0x000000011ab46d38 sip_api_invoke_slot + 753
21  QtCore.so                       0x000000011ac6d597 PyQtProxy::invokeSlot(qpycore_slot const&, void**) + 179
22  QtCore.so                       0x000000011ac6d885 PyQtProxy::unislot(void**) + 117
23  QtCore.so                       0x000000011ac6d975 PyQtProxy::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 95
24  QtCore                          0x000000010f5bc2e2 QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) + 2146
25  QtGui                           0x000000010fee5ef1 QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) + 49
```

Comment: how did you install gdal on Mac? Any other sources used? Have you tried Kyngchaos http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: I used the kyngchaos installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the most up to date versions, kids! Reinstalled QGIS and used latest GDAL framework package (also from kyngchaos, just more recent). Solved the problem.

I'm very sorry to waste your time. But, hey, I learned some new debugging tricks for Mac OS X.